NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents inside XPC Service
I have an issue with XPC Service not being able to register global event handler for mouse clicks.
The XPC Service setup has nothing extraordinary. A usual XPC Service. Starts and works just fine. The .plist:
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>XPCService</key>
    <dict>
        <key> ServiceType</key>
        <string>Application</string>
        <key>JoinExistingSession</key>
        <true/>
        <key>RunLoopType</key>
        <string>NSRunLoop</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Then in one of my XPC methods I do:
self.monitorSystemWide = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.leftMouseDown]) { [weak self] event in
    NSLog(event.debugDescription)
}

The handler is never called even though monitorSystemWide is not nil after addGlobalMonitorForEvents returned.
Is it because some RunLoop aspects in the XPCService or generally it is not possible?
